# OleDbDataAdapter can't not update the access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use `OleDbCommand` to run the `sqlcommand` that can update the Access database.
But when I try to use `OleDbDataAdapter` and `DataTable` to update the database,
it doesn't work.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from confirm", conn);
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["k"] = "november";
            row["v"] = "eleven";
           // table.AcceptChanges();
            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.Update(table);
           // table.AcceptChanges();
            return table;
        }
```

When I run the code, the database doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `DataRow row = table.NewRow();` creates a row with table shema but doesn't add the row to the `DataTable`. You need to add the row to the table :

```
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

complete code

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from confirm", conn);
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row("k") = "november";
    row("v") = "eleven";

    //**You missed this**
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    adapter.Update(table);
    // table.AcceptChanges();
    return table;
}
```